# За что отвечает переменная i, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, функции

у меня есть функция, принимающая произвольное количество аргументов и выводящая их в параграфы, пытаюсь разобраться в логике, для чего здесь ", i" во второй строчке кода ? (код из учебника)

```js
function isField(){ 
    let l = arguments.length, i; 
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    window.document.write('<p>',arguments[i],'</p>')
}
isField('super', 1, 2 , 3 ,'glass')
```

Comment: Так сокращают index.

Comment: а зачем его указывать во второй строчке кода? без этого указания код также работает

Comment: Обычно пишут ```for (let i = 0; ...)```.

Comment: `let l = arguments.length, i;` - это объявление и инициализация переменной l и объявление переменной i

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Вторая строчка кода

   ```js
   let l = arguments.length, i;
   ```

   равносильна двум строчкам

   ```js
   let l = arguments.length;
   let i;
   ```

   (за переменную с именем `l` нужно убивать) и служит для объявления переменной `i`
2. > а зачем его указывать во второй строчке кода? без этого указания код также работает

   работает потому, что ваш код работает в режиме совместимости и все необъявленные переменные автоматически объявляются в глобальной области видимости. Стоит ваш код перевести в строгий режим директивой `'use strict';` и код работать перестанет

   ```js
   "use strict";

   function isField() {
     let l = arguments.length;
     for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
       window.document.write('<p>', arguments[i], '</p>')
   }
   isField('super', 1, 2, 3, 'glass')
   ```
3. И последнее переменную цикла лучше объявлять в самом цикле

   ```js
   for (let i = 0; i < l; i++)
   ```

Comment: спасибо Вам за подробный ответ!